# Collision not working on the ceiling

Tags: lua, coronasdk

All the collisions are working except the *"ceiling"* what am I missing here?

```
local screenGroup = self.view

jetSpriteSheet = sprite.newSpriteSheet("helicopters.png", 97, 55) 
jetSprites = sprite.newSpriteSet(jetSpriteSheet, 1, 4)
sprite.add(jetSprites, "jets", 1, 8, 600, 0)
jet = sprite.newSprite(jetSprites)
jet.x = -80
jet.y = 350
jet:prepare("jets")
jet:play()
jet.collided = false
jet.name = "jetplayer"

physics.addBody(jet, "dynamic", {density=.1, bounce=0.1, friction=.2, radius=10, filter=playerCollisionFilter } )   
jet.gravityScale = 0

jetIntro = transition.to(jet,{time=2000, x=150, onComplete=jetReady})
screenGroup:insert(jet)

ceiling = display.newImage("invisibleTile.png")
ceiling.name = "ceiling"
ceiling:setReferencePoint(display.BottomLeftReferencePoint)
ceiling.x = 0
ceiling.y = 0

physics.addBody(ceiling, "static", {density=.1, bounce=0.1, friction=.2,} )  
screenGroup:insert(ceiling)

local function onCollision(event)
    if event.phase == "began" and gameIsActive == true then
    local obj1 = event.object1; 
    local obj2 = event.object2; 
        if obj1.name == "jetplayer" then
            if     obj2.name == "BCloud1" then MinLife()
            elseif obj2.name == "BCloud2" then pontsMin10()
            elseif obj2.name == "BCloud3" then pontsMin20()
            elseif obj2.name == "GCloud1" then pontsplus50()
            elseif obj2.name == "ceiling" then explode()
            elseif obj2.name == "theFloor" then explode()
            end
        end
    end
end
Runtime:addEventListener( "collision", onCollision )
```

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of image you are using but, physic objects' reference points are always center of the object. So if you are checking without physics.setDrawMode( "debug" ) property you may be misled

Answer (score 1):

Just replace the following line:

```
physics.addBody(app, "dynamic", {density=.1, bounce=0.1, friction=.2, radius=10, filter=playerCollisionFilter } )
```

as below, and check again:

```
physics.addBody(app, "dynamic", {density=.1, bounce=0.1, friction=.2,filter=playerCollisionFilter } )
```

I am not fully aware of this behavior of corona. Here the object with radius (`jetplayer`) is choosen as `obj2`. So, either you may remove the radius, if not needed, or change the function as:

```
if(obj1.name == "jetplayer" or obj2.name == "jetplayer")then
    if(obj1.name == "ceiling" or obj2.name == "ceiling")then
        explode()
    end
end
```

Keep coding..........:)